# Android/Java how to know the radio type of connected wifi

Tags: java, android, wifi

I have been looking into for a while now,I wanted to know the radio type(i.e 802.11n or 802.11g etc...) of the connected wifi Ap. i have looked into every possible Android or java api but not able to find out. i also tried reading the proc file system but no info regarding the radio type is available there also.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not quite sure about it but, have you tried looking into ScanResult.capabilities http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#capabilities